# Accessing QGIS element variables in Composer

Tags: qgis, print-composer

Is there a way to access "other" composer element variables in QGIS?

I can "print" a variable in a text element by inputing for example: [% @project_title %], but is there a way to use the *map_scale* variable from a map element?

Anyting like: [% @map0(map_scale) %] ?

Comment: Not built in, no. You could possibly write a custom python function which would do this though.

Comment: That's cool! Could you give an example of such a function or point us to a tutorial?

Answer (score 3):

I do not have the answer for the general question, but in the specific case you pointed at, using "map scale" I do the following:

```
[%'Scale: 1:' || round(map_get(item_variables('Map 1'), 'map_scale')/100) || '00'%]
```

For this to work you have to give an ID to the desiderd map:
[image: Assign an ID to the map]

(Done w/ Qgs 3.10)

Hope it hepls!